# Getting "Codesign operation failed" when archiving for Mac App Store

Tags: xcode, xcode4.3, mac-app-store

After I archive my app and select "Submit to the Mac App Store" and select my Application and Code Signing Identity I get a "Codesign operation failed" error. I have my target/project Code Signing Identity set to "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: Joe Hopkins" which is the correct certificate for for my production Application identifier, and according to my keychain my certificates are valid so I don't know what the issue would be.

I realize there is a similar question that the issue was nested folders with the same name but this appears to be a different issue.

Anyone have any ideas on how to troubleshoot?

Thanks.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue...

It was not related to certificates or provisioning. I fixed it by recreating my project and relinking in my resources. I am not exactly sure what specific issue was creating the issue but I originally had a "Resources" folder and removing that may of been what solved the issue.